# Includes stdafx.h winsock2 redefinition errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6, include

When I include winsock2.h, I get about 60 redefinition errors.  I hunted around a bit a found some advice to include winsock2.h b4 including windows.h.  I did that and that cleared up the errors.  My problem and question concerns exactly how I should go about doing this.  I did not explicitly include windows.h, it was done for me in stdafx.h or stdafx.cpp.

I added the include winsock2.h immediately b4 the include Windows.h in stdafx.h.  Is this the right way to go about this or is there a better way?

Judging by a comment in program_name.rc I gather the windows.h include in stdafx.h may have been placed there as a result of some option or configuration parameter but I was unable to find this reference.  Is there some way to specify what files are included in stdafx.h?

BTW, WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN was defined b4 calling windows.h in stdafx.h.

I am using Visual c++ 6.0 and 'Windows Server 2003 PSDK'  The program is straight c++, no mfc, no net, just plain vanilla.

Answer (score 3):

You can put pretty much whatever you want into stdafx.h. It's certainly fine to add your #include for winsock2.h before the windows.h. I'd move the WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN header so that it's defined before you include any other headers:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

stdafx.h is a horrendous name for the precompiled header. I have no idea why Visual Studio still uses this for all the autogenerated projects. It gives the precompiled header an undeserved air of mystery. In my projects I usually set up the precompiled header to use 'precompiled.h' and 'precompiled.cpp'.

Noel Llopis has a great article on precompiled headers - '[The Care and Feeding of Precompiled Headers](http://gamesfromwithin.com/the-care-and-feeding-of-pre-compiled-headers)' if you want a bit more background info on what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

That should work okay. If you look in winsock2.h, you can see that it includes windows.h if it hasn't already been included.

Comment: Judging by the comments in stdafx.h and stdafx.cpp, it is intended that the user add additional includes to stdafx.h.  I'm a bit curious about the comment in stdafx.cpp

// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes

// Solar.pch will be the pre-compiled header

// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information

What is meant by 'type' information? Could someone give an example?

Comment: By adding includes to stdafx.h, I *think* the precompiled headers are more efficient spacewise. But I know precompiled headers work without stdafx.* if you turn the option in in the project settings. At least Visual Studio always creates a .pch for all of my projects even though I don't have stdafx.* stuff. Someone else might have more info on 'type' information. I think, though, it is still just part of the information that it uses in conjunction with the .pch file for building.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that WinSock2.h is included BEFORE windows.h, make sure that wherever you're including WinSock2.h, it is included before stdafx.h and/or windows.h